# \node_modules\@types\angular\index.d.ts(243,41): error TS100

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio

I'm using Angular 4 and out of seemingly nowhere, I started getting the following build error in my

```
>  \node_modules\@types\angular\index.d.ts(243,41): error TS100
```

**tsconfig.json**

```html
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
      },
      "compileOnSave": true
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV1ex.png)

Comment: share your *tsconfig.json* here

Comment: I don't think you need separate angular types.

Comment: Try running ng build --prod, it will figure out syntax or functional error in your code, if any.

Comment: @Prachi Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is type script version im using is lower then my node version.. So i updated my typescript to latest version and also upgraded my node to latest...

You can upgrade your node using below link [enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Download latest typescript using below link [enter link description here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258)